# A better way to do this triple loop using numpy methods

Tags: performance, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

So I'm just trying to write a simple script to convert RBG to YUV and I have ended up with something like this:

```
rgb2yuv_matrix = np.array([[0.299, 0.587, 0.114], [-0.1473, -0.28886, 0.436],[0.615, -0.51499, 0.10001]])
for i in range(n_train):
    for j in range(32):
        for k in range(32):
            # Note here that X_train[i, j, k] is a 3 element array
            X_train[i,j,k] = np.dot(rgb2yuv_matrix, X_train[i,j,k])
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this since I know a triple loop is very inefficient, but I don't know if there is a better way to do it in numpy.

Comment: Yes as that is how the RGB values are converted to the YUV values

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that X[i, j, k] is a 3 dimensional vector (one for each color)

Comment: In NumPy terms, that would mean a 3 elem array. So, edited accordingly. Hope that's okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
np.tensordot(X_train, rgb2yuv_matrix, axes=([-1],[1]))
```

Basically, we are sum-reducing the last axis of `X_train` against the second (also the last) axis of `rgb2yuv_matrix`.

---

You could probably gain some performance for small arrays with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) that would also involve some reshaping, like so -

```
X_train.reshape(-1,3).dot(rgb2yuv_matrix.T).reshape(X_train.shape)
```

---

### Benchmarking

```
In [25]: def original_app(X_train, rgb2yuv_matrix, n_train, m):
    ...:     for i in range(n_train):
    ...:         for j in range(m):
    ...:             for k in range(m):
    ...:                 X_train[i,j,k] = np.dot(rgb2yuv_matrix, X_train[i,j,k])
    ...:                 

In [26]: # Setup inputs
    ...: n_train = 1000
    ...: m = 32
    ...: X_train = np.random.rand(n_train,m,m,3)
    ...: rgb2yuv_matrix = np.array([[0.299, 0.587, 0.114], \
    ...:                            [-0.1473, -0.28886, 0.436],\
    ...:                            [0.615, -0.51499, 0.10001]])
    ...: 

In [27]: %timeit original_app(X_train, rgb2yuv_matrix, n_train, m)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.45 s per loop

In [28]: %timeit np.tensordot(X_train, rgb2yuv_matrix, axes=([-1],[1]))
10 loops, best of 3: 22 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit X_train.reshape(-1,3).dot(rgb2yuv_matrix.T).reshape(X_train.shape)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.6 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matmul()`:

```
a = np.random.rand(3, 3)
b = np.random.rand(10, 32, 32, 3)
c = np.matmul(a, b[..., None]).squeeze()
```